# Cant import my csv file in jupyter notebbok

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, opencsv

I have put my CSV file in the same folder as running jupyter notebook, still can't able to import it.

Comment: Can you show us what code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need read to a df first:

df = pd.read_csv('name.csv')  # (the file name of your csv) 
df